# Database Design Issue - Different Statuses for Different Sex

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

**SCENARIO**

I want to design tables for saving Data of ***Cattle*** and ***Calfs***.

**Attributes/columns Common among Cattle and Calf**

- Price
- Birth Date
  etc. (Some coming from FK as well like Breed etc)

**Attributes reserved for Calf**

- Father
- Mother

**Attributes reserved for CATTLE (Female)**

- IsMilking (Y or N)
- InseminationDate (Off course a cow can be inseminated a number of times so it must be normalized and a new table should be there as: ID (FK using PK of CATTLE table) and InsemDate - but it should be present only for FEMALE)

**There is a Special attribute of *Status* for CATTLE having following Properties:**

- Common Among both genders: {*Healthy, Ill*}
- Reserved for Female ONLY: {*Pregnant, Heifer, etc.*}

My whole Software is failing due to this incompetent design. My existing design is as follows:

**Existing Design**

There is one table for CATTLE referencing all STATUS, BREED, etc tables as it's FK.

There is a table of CALF having these columns:

```
ID (FK from CATTLE table) - Having cattle and calf in same table is apparently failing
FatherID (FK from CATTLE table) - Again we can have Calfs themselves as Father in this column
MotherID (FK from CATTLE table) - Same issue
```

Thanks In Advance. I have tried as hard as I could do. Split the tables for MALE and FEMALE (but it costs inheritance and I have to split all the subsequent tables like STATUS table etc as well).

Comment: A record indicating "unknown parent" would allow you to have all the animals in the same table.

Comment: And its design? Do you mean Calf_Father and Mother columns should be in the animals table as well?

Comment: I'm not a farmer, but doesn't calves that aren't slaughtered become cattle (cows, bulls and oxen)? Why wouldn't you want to store information about parents for all animals - isn't the ability to trace lineage important in all cases and not just for the children?

Comment: @jpw Haha. It is important but actually many animals are purchased, so no whereabouts of their ancestors. And yes calfs will be moved to CATTLE status after a certain duration (18 months I reckon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is too broad and many possible answer, but I tried to since I'm into database designing.

It's not perfect but I hope it can help you a little.

Calf Table (Calf records)

[image]

Relationships to Cattle 2x

[image]

Cattle Table (Cattle records)

[image]

Cattle Relationships

[image]

Insemination Table (Insem records)

[image]

Special Attribute Table

[image]

Special Attribute Record Table

[image]

Special Attribute Value Table

[image]

Calves View

[image]

Cattle Status View

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am thankful the way you explained it in so much detail

Comment: Didn't it help you? We can discuss what needs improvement.

Comment: How to prevent male Cattles from using female cattles statuses? In Insemination table, we can add Male cattle's ID as well

Comment: You can add a Gender column in Cattle table that will contain values Male and Female. Then on Special_Attribute table you can add a column named ForGender and it will contain Male and Female values as well. For example Pregnancy will have a ForGender value of Female. Finally you can add "AND Cattle.Gender = Special_Attribute.ForGender" on your ON clause for Cattle inner joining Special_Attribute table.

Comment: For adding insemination, you can tell your application to get only cattles with gender Female.

Comment: I could do the other things in Front-end as well if it was the purpose. I want to have a strong back-end design as well. Anyways can you generate the script of whole tables etc you made and paste on pastebin?

Answer (score 1):

I think one table for the animal with a self-relationship for father and mother is the way to go. Something like this;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Animal](
    [AnimalID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Sex] [char](1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [Animal_Sex] CHECK  (([Sex]='F' OR [Sex]='M')),
    [Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Price] [money] NULL,
    [BirthDate] [date] NULL,
    [Father_AnimalID] [int] NULL,
    [Father_Sex]  AS (CONVERT([char](1),'M')) PERSISTED,
    [Mother_AnimalID] [int] NULL,
    [Mother_Sex]  AS (CONVERT([char](1),'F')) PERSISTED,
    [IsMilking] [char](1) NULL,
    [HealthStatus] [char](1) NULL,
    [FemaleStatus] [char](1) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Animal] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AnimalID]),
    CONSTRAINT [AK_Animal] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([AnimalID], [Sex])
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Animal] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Animal_Animal_Father] 
    FOREIGN KEY([Father_AnimalID], [Father_Sex]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Animal] ([AnimalID], [Sex])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Animal] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Animal_Animal_Mother] 
    FOREIGN KEY([Mother_AnimalID], [Mother_Sex]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Animal] ([AnimalID], [Sex])
```

Note how I've added a couple of constant computed columns (Father_Sex and Mother_Sex) - this lets me create a more sophisticated foreign key for the father and mother that forces the father to be male and the mother to be female, and indirectly prevents father and mother from being the same animal.

Comment: Thank you Rhys! I am still skeptical about some attributes though

Answer (score 1):

Create an Animal table that contains the attributes and status that are common to all.  This would include the parent FKs, self-referencing an unknown Animal if the lineage is not available

Then create separate "extended" tables for the attributes for a specific gender or stage.  Cow, Bull, Calf, etc.  You can re-use the PK from the Animal table as the PK for the extended tables as it is a 1:1 relationship.

This would also allow for Animal status separate from gender status, so you could have a Healthy Animal as a Pregnant Cattle.

I did this in the past for an adoption agency application.  They had a people table with the common attributes, but attributes that were specific to the birth mother or child were placed in dedicated tables. There were 30+ additional fields gathered for each.  Birth mom/child records only accounted for 25-30% of the people records so it made sense to separate them rather than add 60+ fields to the primary table that were guaranteed to be null.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wes.